# Save computer-accessible file from Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I would like to let a user save a file from my app (Xamarin.Forms) to a computer. Since this seems impossible directly, I'd like to let him save the file on the device, so that he can then connect the device to a computer and copy it.

I've tried saving to a couple of [SpecialFolder](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Environment+SpecialFolder/)'s including `MyPictures` (the writing succeeds but I can't find it on file explorer), `CommonPictures` (the path is ""), `MyDocuments` (same as `MyPictures`),...

So how can this be done?

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question about ios? Wouldn't it be easier to use a service like DropBox so you can implement this once across platforms and the user does not have to physically connect the phone to a pc?

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to refrain from using the cloud as much as possible. The only reason I even mentioned it about iOS was because I thought there would be no other way at all. And by the way, I was sure Android would be simple since I did something similar in the past. But it seems that's only when dealing with media...

Comment: I'm quite sure you saved it somewhere into the system areas of the android file system and you will have to save to something like /mnt/sdcard/yourfolder because the latter is only available to you on a rooted device. Of course, this path can vary by device/android version.

Comment: I use this in one of my android projects: `var imageRoot = System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath, "MyProjectName");` - those files are accessible just fine from PC.

Comment: @LaszloTenki I'm not saving to an SD card. And I need this to work on non-rooted devices too. Is there no (simple) way to transfer arbitrary type files from a device to a PC?

Comment: @Evk I tried that. And thanks, it does show up in the device's file manager. But unfortunately not in the PC's (Windows 10). The `Pictures` folder there is empty.

Comment: @Evk I now see the files with the PC, but only after restarting the device and disconnecting+reconnecting it. Strange.

Comment: Well maybe there is some problems with device\drivers. Happens quite often in my practice with android devices.